# How to expose a Kubernetes-Service running on a AWS EKS Cluster with Fargate to the Internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, networking, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

Hi and thanks in advance for your replies.

I am trying to expose the following deployment on our AWS EKS Cluster. All pods are running on Fargate-nodes.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: ssd-namespace-01
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-reverse-proxy
        image: nginx-reverse-proxy
```

I have tried the following:

1.Expose command:

`kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --port=80 --target-port=80 --name nginx-exposed-svc --type LoadBalancer`

2.Applying a Service-Manifest with annotations

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: ssd-namespace-01
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external 
    kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
    kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx-deployment
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
```

Issue:
While a Loadbalancer is indeed created and "kubectl get svc" returns an EXTERNAL-IP (or rather a URL) for the service, I cannot reach it. Http Requests in the browser fail and Postman gives me "Error: socket hang up". I thought maybe a Security Group blocks the connection, but we cannot find the culprit.

Do you have any suggestion on how to find out, where the connection is being blocked?

Comment: First, try connecting to your service using `kubectl port-forward`. For example for your service you would run `kubectl port-forward -n ssd-namespace-01 svc/nginx-service 8080:80` and then browse to localhost:8080. If you get a 200 OK, there's probably something the SGs or the load balancer configuration.

Comment: Thanks! That already helped me a lot. I indeed get status 200, when I forward the port. We will be looking for a misconfigured SG or LB. Any suggestions for how to find the culprit would be much appreciated.

Comment: The backend service has to be configured to accept traffic from the VPC CIDR and/or the internet (0.0.0.0/0). It depends on whether you've configured to preserve the ip address of the requestor. See https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.5/guide/service/nlb/#security-group. The AWS Load Balancer Controller should configure this automatically for you.